# I'm trying to solve ode45

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve problem with **ode45.**

In ode45, x' and x'' are used. then, I want to drive from ode45 to equation of x.

I tried to solve with polyfit function.

```
polyfit(t,y,4)
```

but error occurred 'X and Y vectors must be the same size.'

I don't know what I should.

In my opinion, it seems to be able to solve with integral function. This correct??

It would be very appreciated if you handle it, and tell me how to solve.

code below :

my code is constructed with main script and function.

```
clear
global L M m f Jw rw Fz Cd p A bw fw Nw g uw seta Te Tb y_curve X Q
L=[0 0.025 0.05 0.1 0.125 0.15 0.175 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 0.5 0.55 0.6 0.65 0.7 0.75 0.8 0.85 0.9 0.95 1];
M=[0 0.225 0.45 0.65 0.685 0.705 0.69 0.68 0.65 0.635 0.63 0.6275 0.625 0.6225 0.62 0.6175 0.615 0.6125 0.610 0.6075 0.6050 0.6 0.5975 0.5950];

m = 1400;  f= 0.01;  Jw = 0.65; rw= 0.31; Fz = 3560; Cd = 0.5; p = 1.202; 
A = 1.95; bw = 0; fw = 0; Nw = 4; g = 9.81; uw = 0; seta = 0; Te = 0; Tb = 1000;
X=polyfit(L,M,20);
x_curve = 0:0.025:1;
y_curve = polyval(X,x_curve);
[t,i] = ode45('dot',[0:0.1:1],[20 20]);
Q = polyfit(t,i,4);
%subplot(1, 2, 1);
%plot(L,M,'p',x_curve,y_curve,'m');
xlabel('Lamda')
ylabel('mu'); grid;

%subplot(1, 2, 2);
plot(t,i); grid on;
xlabel('time(s)');
ylabel('x');
```

```
function xdot = dot(t,x)
global m f Jw rw Fz Cd p A Nw Te Tb g Y X 
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%Detailed explanation goes here
xdot = zeros(2,1);

lamda = (x(2)-x(1))/x(1);

Y=X(1,1)*(lamda)^20+X(1,2)*(lamda)^19+X(1,3)*(lamda)^18+X(1,4)*(lamda)^17+X(1,5)*(lamda)^16+X(1,6)*(lamda)^15+X(1,7)*(lamda)^14+X(1,8)*(lamda)^13+X(1,9)*(lamda)^12+X(1,10)*(lamda)^11+X(1,11)*(lamda)^10+X(1,12)*(lamda)^9+X(1,13)*(lamda)^8+X(1,14)*(lamda)^7+X(1,15)*(lamda)^6+X(1,16)*(lamda)^5+X(1,17)*(lamda)^4+X(1,18)*(lamda)^3+X(1,19)*(lamda)^2+X(1,20)*(lamda)^1+X(1,21);
xdot(1)=(-0.5*p*Cd*A*((x(1)*rw)^2)-f*m*g+(Nw*Y*Fz))/(rw*m); 
xdot(2)=(Te-Tb-rw*Y*Fz)/Jw;
end
```

Comment: How did you use `polyfit`? Have you split your problem into 2 first order ODE's? We need some more information to help properly.

Comment: I attached my code. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively easy: the output `i` is 2 columns wide (since there's two elements in `x`), but only 1 column in `t`. So:

```
Q1 = polyfit(t,i(:,1), 4);
Q2 = polyfit(t,i(:,2), 4);
```

does the trick.

I however also get a conditioning problem in your polynomial fit. This problem you can fix this by using the scale/shift option, as documented in `help polyfit`.

There's also a singularity somewhere in your derivative, since the final few entries are `NaN` caused by one of the values of `xdot` growing without bounds. So, you get all `NaN` for the `Q1` and `Q2`.

Below is a version of your code that implements this change, as well as show a few programming practices that are widely considered to be superior to your current style:

- [Don't. Use. Global. Variables.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)
- Prefer functions over scripts
- Document the intention of each distinct atomic operation ("block of commands")
- Choose variable names that provide rudimentary self-documentation of the code
- Don't overuse parenthesis. Use parenthesis where *necessary*, or when they significantly improve reading.
- Spacing between math operators. Makes it a lot easier to identify terms and understand what belongs to what -- a fantastic source of bugs this one.
- Align your code. You write code only once, but *read* it hundreds of times -- make *that* part easiest.
- In MATLAB: if you find yourself doing a repetitive copy-paste job, or a line of code exceeds the 85 column mark, there's probably a shorter, more readable, better understandable, better maintainable 'vectorized' way to do it.

This works over here (R2010a):

```
function myFun

    %// Your data
    L = [0 0.025 0.05 0.1 0.125 0.15 0.175 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 0.5 0.55 0.6 0.65 0.7 0.75 0.8 0.85 0.9 0.95 1];
    M = [0 0.225 0.45 0.65 0.685 0.705 0.69 0.68 0.65 0.635 0.63 0.6275 0.625 0.6225 0.62 0.6175 0.615 0.6125 0.610 0.6075 0.6050 0.6 0.5975 0.5950];

    %// Your coefficients
    A    = 1.95;     m  = 1400;  
    bw   = 0;        f  = 0.01;  
    fw   = 0;        Jw = 0.65; 
    Nw   = 4;        rw = 0.31; 
    g    = 9.81;     Fz = 3560; 
    uw   = 0;        Cd = 0.5; 
    seta = 0;        p  = 1.202;
    Te   = 0;        N  = 20;   %// (degree of polynomial)
    Tb   = 1000;

    %// Find best-fitting polynomial
    [X,~,mu] = polyfit(L,M,N);

    %// Or, if you like, a much faster alternative:
    %// X = bsxfun(@power, (L(:)-mean(L))/std(L), N:-1:0)\M(:);

    %// Plot the poly over the data 
    %// DEBUG -- put a space between the percent sign and brace below to include
    %{ 
    subplot(2,1,1), hold on
    x_curve = 0:0.025:1;
    y_curve = polyval(X,x_curve, [], mu);
    plot(L,M,'p',x_curve,y_curve,'m');
    xlabel('Lambda')
    ylabel('mu'); 
    grid on
    %}

    %// Carry out the integration
    tspan = [0 1];
    x0    = [20 20];
    [t,i] = ode45(@dxdt, tspan, x0);

    %// Fit a polynomal through the solutions
    Q1 = polyfit(t,i(:,1), 4);
    Q2 = polyfit(t,i(:,2), 4);

    %// Plot integration results        
    %// DEBUG -- put a space between the percent sign and brace below to include
    %{
    subplot(2,1,2), hold on
    plot(t,i); 
    grid on    
    xlabel('time(s)');
    ylabel('x');
    %}

    %// The time derivative
    function xdot = dxdt(~,x)

        %// Polynomial value for these X
        Y = ((x(2)-x(1))/x(1)).^(N:-1:0) * X.';  %'

        %// The derivative:
        xdot = [
            (-p/2*Cd*A*(x(1)*rw)^2 - f*m*g + Nw*Y*Fz)/rw/m
            (Te - Tb - rw*Y*Fz)/Jw
         ];

    end    

end
```

Note that the `%//` and `%'` are just there to make code formatting on SO work for everyone.

Comment: Thank you very much. I realized that i need to trainning hard.